# Using tf.tile or tf.expand_dims to replicate a tensor in some way

Tags: python, tensorflow

Based on tensorflow functions.
There is a tensor A=[1 10 5 6]. How could I create a tensor B which looks like the following:

```
[[[1  1  1 ],[1  1  1 ],[1  1  1 ]],
 [[10 10 10],[10 10 10],[10 10 10]],
 [[5  5  5 ],[5  5  5 ],[5  5  5 ]],
 [[6  6  6 ],[6  6  6 ],[6  6  6 ]]]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
A_reshape = tf.expand_dims(A,1)
A_reshape = tf.expand_dims(A_reshape,2)
B = tf.tile(A_reshape, [1,3,3])
```

Comment: You can also simplify the first two steps as `A_reshape = tf.reshape(A, [-1, 1, 1])` or `A_reshape = A[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis]`.